# Android - Sort values in Spinner alphabetically without losing id

Tags: android, sorting, spinner

I have a few stringarray's in my project, and they need to be sorted alphabetically. However, since the previous guy heavily relied on spinner id's, I can't make it so that the id's of every value changes.

Meaning that if my list looks like this now (id's after it):

```
- cat(0)
- dog(1) 
- book(2)
```

I want it changed to this:

```
- book(2)
- cat(0)
- dog(1)
```

(Just to make it clear, the numbers in the `()'s` are id's and shouldn't be in the value)
Is this a possibility?

Regards,
Riekelt

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("cat(0)");
list.add("book(1)");
...................
Collection.sort(list);
```

**UPDATE**

```
class StringItem {
    String text;
    int id;
}

ArrayList<StringItem> list = new ArrayList();
//Add the items and then perform sort as:
Collection.sort(list, new ItemComparator());

private class ItemComparator implements Comparator<StringItem> {
    @Override
    public int compare(StringItem i1, StringItem i2) {
        return i2.text.compareTo(i1.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this'll keep the id's the same.

Comment: Then can you not define something like this? class item { String text, int id} and then have a arraylist of type item. Sort the array list based on the text entry.

Comment: The ID's I'm referring too are spinner id's. So I'd guess I have to perform a transformation after the one is filled